# windows service code in c ,where to write service logic code?

Tags: c, windows, service, winsock, winexe

the title is quite general but my doubt is specific.
I have doubt regarding where to write the service logic code (in service control handler or in ServiceMain),as in whatever the functionality the service would perform . Is it in ServiceMain ?
 I have looked upon these topics on MSDN relate to service. But ,didn't help me
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687414%28VS.85%29.aspx
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Basically, I want to start a socket listening on windows using a service. This listening socket logic code will be in service file because of I am going to use winexe utility to send this service from linux box to windows box. currently, winexe sends the winexesvc service file on windows. So, ultimately I am going to replace the existing winexesvc service so that it will perform listening on a particular port function when sent on windows. (Service skeleton would remain same but its task performing logic will change,right?). please tell if I am missing anything.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service control handler should only, well, handle control messages that are sent to the service (the ones shown in the examples  you linked are `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` and `SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE`). These control messages are sent to the service from the environment.

The logic of your service should be implemented in the `ServiceMain` function, when all required initialization is done. In the example at the URL in your post, the service logic code is put into the `SvcInit` function (which is probably not the most appropriate name for a function that implements logic of a service).

Comment: yes,actually in winexe code , they have implemented the service logic code in serviceInitialization function where a new thread for server_loop is created. I still haven't tested the changed code for service ,still looks fine for what I was looking for.
But , couldn't find ServiceMain function. Can ServiceMain function be called with different name ?

Comment: Yes, it can have any name. You can find it in the dispatch table which is passed to the `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` function.